# Jquery Fade not working

Tags: jquery

I am using this jquery to show a div on top of another one when it is hovered over, but for some reason even though it seems to work the fadeIN and fadeOUT don't work.

if I change the fadeTo to `fadeIn` and `fadeOut` respectively then that breaks it as the previous one you hover over dosen't disappear?

```
$(function() {
$(".report-hover").hover(
    function() {
        $(this).children("img").fadeTo(200, 0.85).end().children(".report-image-hover").show();
    },
    function() {
        $(this).children("img").fadeTo(200, 1).end().children(".report-image-hover").hide();
    });
});
```

Markup:

```
<div class="report-hover">

                <div class="report-image-hover">
                <a href="#">
                <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/.....png" alt="Report" />
                </a>
                </div>

                <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/.....png" alt="Report" />
</div>
```

Comment: Can you show us your markup as well?

Comment: I made an example markup. More than likely not the same as OP's. http://jsfiddle.net/yCCGt/

Comment: @m90 I have added the markup for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this: [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zaheerahmed/yCCGt/3/)

If you are just replacing FadeTo to FadeIn then it will not work because FadeIn has different parameters. [JQuery FadeIn](http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/)

Comment: The values for fadeTo are perfectly valid: http://api.jquery.com/fadeTo/ this is a DOM traversal issue.

Comment: @m90 yes For fadeTo it is perfect, but for fadeIn it is not.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `.find()` instead of `.children()` when you are selecting the image to fade out. `.children()` will only select direct descendants and your image is still nested inside a `div`. See **[the docs](http://api.jquery.com/children/)**:

> The .children() method differs from .find() in that .children() only
>   travels a single level down the DOM tree while .find() can traverse
>   down multiple levels to select descendant elements (grandchildren,
>   etc.) as well.

For your code that turns into:

```
$(".report-hover").hover(
    function() {
        $(this).find("img").fadeTo(200, 0.85).end().children(".report-image-hover").show();
    },
    function() {
        $(this).find("img").fadeTo(200, 1).end().children(".report-image-hover").hide();
});
```